# Delete all lines containing ".." and "@"

Tags: text-processing

I have a long text file from a `tcpdump`. I need some of the information but most lines are just like this:

```
.....@isa..g..3..2..2.@...3.3.2.1.12..
```

I want to use sed to search and replace all lines containing `@` and `..`

I have tried this

```
sed -i '/foo\../foo_/d' ./file\ 2.txt
sed '/@/d' ./file\ 2.txt
awk '!/@/' file\ 2.txt
```

And the file is on the desktop and its called `file 2` and I have done `cd Desktop`. That doesn't matter since the error code I get is not a "directory not found".

Comment: So what error _do_ you get?

Comment: You need it to be with sed, or anything will do?

Comment: Doesn't matter, anything will do

Answer (score 5):

To *delete* lines that contain both `..` and `@`:

```
awk '!/@/ || !/\.\./'
```

Or:

```
sed -e '/@/!b' -e '/\.\./d'
```

Or as [suggested by @rush](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148964/delete-all-lines-containing-and-sed/148966?noredirect=1#comment241941_148966):

```
sed '/@/{/\.\./d;}'
```

Comment: You can also use `sed '/@/{/\.\./d}'` which is a bit shorter :)

Comment: @Gnouc, he wants to **delete** the lines that contain both, so he wants to **keep** the lines that don't contain `@` or don't contain `..`. `!/@/ || !/\.\./` is `!(/@/ && /\.\./)`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Oh, Sorry. miss `!` in your answer. My poor vision.